# A way to make all index route models = resource route model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

## UPDATE

Okay, what luck…this is now the default behavior [as of Ember 1.5](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/30/ember-1-5-0-and-ember-1-6-beta-released.html#toc_routes-inherit-model). Yay!

### Original question

Something that really seems intuitive to me but isn't the case in the Ember router. I have a bunch of `resource`s, the vast bulk of which have an `index` route where I want the model to be the same as the resource route's model--that is, the object selected by convention using the dynamic segment. E.g.:

```
this.resource("chargeRule", { path: "/chargeRule/:chargeRule_id" }, function(){});
```

I'm going to be using nesting, so I can't do everything in my `chargeRule` *template*, because that template is going to have little but `{{outlet}}` (kinda like [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012806/idiomatic-emberjs-for-nested-routes-but-non-nested-templates)). So my `index` route is going to be my read-only view in most cases and I'll have an `edit` sub-route to update a model where needed.

What bugs me is, the default model for an `index` route (and any other sub-route) is: NOTHING! Tada! Null I think, though it could be empty string or something. So, I now have to create a bunch of tiny `Ember.Route` subclasses that look exactly like this:

```
App.ChargeRuleIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.modelFor('chargeRule');
    }
});
```

Repeat ad-nauseum for each different model class/route. Really, then about double it because I want the same for `/index` and `/edit` routes, maybe more. Personally, I would have thought that the *default* model (since you can override it anyway) for any child route should have been the parent route's model instead of *nothing*, but I'd be interested in explanations as to why it's not.

But my question is, can anybody come up with a way for me to make the behavior I'm describing the default in my app? Something I can `reopen`? So I don't have a dozen or more boilerplate 5-line route objects?

### Edit

I might should mention that I know my gripe might seem trivial, but the fact that I have to create so many route subclasses also implies that I *should* create individual files for each class…right? So that future developers can easily find where a given class is defined? I know that's not an absolute, but is a good practice, I think, and would require me to make as many tiny JS files as tiny classes…which is why I started thinking in terms of changing the default behavior. I'll take comments on that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UPDATE

See note at top of question, this is no longer necessary...

Based on @kingpin2k 's answer, I came up with this more generalized possibility:

```
App.ParentModelRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.modelFor(this.get('routeName').replace(/\..*$/, ''));
    }
});

App.ChargeRuleIndexRoute = App.ParentModelRoute.extend();
App.ChargeRuleEditRoute = App.ParentModelRoute.extend();
App.OtherIndexRoute = App.ParentModelRoute.extend();
.
.
.
```

Which certainly cuts down on the amount of code…but still requires me to explicitly declare a route class for each sub-route. It also may be a bit hacky (the `routeName` property isn't listed in the API docs?), though it's simple enough it should work pretty widely.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is due to the fact that a route doesn't necessarily have to contain a model.  Think of the case of a `Albums/New` route.  It wouldn't actually have the albums resource as its model.  For this reason there is no set rule for what the model should be for a model.

That being said, if you feel like lazily building up some sort of default route for your route and extending this, that's entirely possible and can be accomplished a few different ways.

```
App.DefaultChargeRuleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.modelFor('chargeRule');
    }
});

App.ChargeRuleIndexRoute = App.DefaultChargeRuleRoute.extend();

App.ChargeRuleEditRoute = App.DefaultChargeRuleRoute.extend();
```

or if you wanted to make some generic model fetching route

```
App.ModelFetcherRoute = Ember.Mixin.create({
  model: function(){
    return this.modelFor(this.get('modelToFetch'));
  }
});


App.ChargeRuleIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.ModelFetcherRoute, {
  modelToFetch: 'chargeRule'
});
```

And this could follow the same pattern as the first example if you want to make it even smaller

```
App.DefaultChargeRuleRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.ModelFetcherRoute, {
  modelToFetch: 'chargeRule'
});

App.ChargeRuleIndexRoute = App.DefaultChargeRuleRoute.extend();

App.ChargeRuleEditRoute = App.DefaultChargeRuleRoute.extend();
```

Comment: Hmm! You got me thinking about making a more general `Ember.Route` subclass, which I hadn't thought of before for some reason. Thanks, I'm now thinking in the direction of making it even more general...

Comment: Oh, and I get why you're saying this isn't the default. Loading up all the `Album`s because I hit the `/new` sub route could indeed be horribly inefficient at best.