# ember-cli / pod: Nesting resources/templates

Tags: templates, ember.js, routes, nested-resources

I have read various stackoverflow threads and other forum entries, but I am not able to figure out how to get nested resources/templates working using **ember-cli 0.1.12** and **pod** structure.

Versions:

- Ember      : 1.8.1 (also tried 1.9.1)
- Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.12
- Handlebars : 1.3.0 (also tried 2.0.0)
- jQuery     : 1.11.2

My router.js (unchanged, cli created it, only demo purposes):

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("controls", function() {
    this.route("statements");
    this.resource("handles", function() {});
});
```

**Situation:**

- No additional modifications besides ember generate commands and text markers in the created template.hbs
- Resource "controls": template is displayed as expected
- Route "controls/statements": template is displayed as expected
- Resource "handles" under resource "controls" is not rendered at at all.
- Subsequent routes unter "controls/handles" are also not working.
- When I invoke http://localhost:4200/controls/handles, ember inspector only list "application" and "controls" in the view tree. In the ember inspector routes section, it lists: handles.index
  HandlesIndexRoute Send to console
  HandlesIndexController Send to console
  handles/index
  /controls/handles

**I tried:**

- Switching ember and handlebar versions - no effect
- Not using pod structure - no effect
- Manually adding an index.hbs template in the handles pod folder - no effect

I have the feeling that I am missing a basic point here.
Could you please help me out?

Thank you, 
Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help on the pod issue but can try on the other point.
What is the nature of your nested resource?

I would be expecting URLs like: "..controls/:control_id/handles".

I would have written this like this:

```
this.resource('controls', function() {
  this.route('statements');
  this.route('show', { path: ':control_id' }, function() {
    this.resource('handles', function() {
    });
  });
});
```

Nick

Comment: Thanks. I have the requirement to use different templates on different routes/resources, e.g. have a "main" resource building the foundation for all main functionalities. On the other hand a "misc" resource covering login, registration, error, and other functionalities template-wise. I learned that template-nesting means route-nesting. So, my application.hbs only contains {{outlet}}, the main template includes nav and other standard components and the inner-nested resources bring in the specific payload.

Comment: Yes, the templates are nested. The Ember Inspector in Chrome lets you see it easily. To control the template nesting, see this SO question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012806/idiomatic-emberjs-for-nested-routes-but-non-nested-templates). What exactly is the hierarchy that you want? nick